# How can i add two text values on select input with left and right position?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown like the one below. But I have no idea how can i do that. Somehow I manage and add an icon on the left side but now I want to add text on the right side on all options. Below is the screenshot. Please help me to fix this.

I need something like the below.

[image]

```html
<style>
.price-dropdown.facebook {
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em 0.2em 2em;
  background-image: url(https://dev.sidesmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/website-24x24-1-24x24.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0.8em auto;
  background-position: 0.4em center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
</style>
<select class="price-dropdown select facebook">
   <option value="" selected="" disabled="">--- Select Quantity ---</option>
   <option selected="" value="9.99">250</option>
   <option value="18">500</option>
   <option value="29">1000</option>
   <option value="54">2000</option>
   <option value="69">5000</option>
</select>
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Best would probably be to make a custom select.

Comment: @Geshode I am a backend developer. I have no idea how can i make this. Can you please help me or suggest me any link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Multi-select

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        
         var multipleCancelButton = new Choices('#choices-multiple-remove-button', {
            removeItemButton: true,
            maxItemCount:5,
            searchResultLimit:5,
            renderChoiceLimit:5
          }); 
         
         
     });
```

```css
.mt-100{margin-top: 100px}body{background: #00B4DB;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0083B0, #00B4DB);background: linear-gradient(to right, #0083B0, #00B4DB);color: #514B64;min-height: 100vh}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bbbootstrap/libraries@main/choices.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bbbootstrap/libraries@main/choices.min.js"></script>
   
      
          <select class="price-dropdown select facebook" id="choices-multiple-remove-button" placeholder="Select upto 5 tags" multiple>
   <option value="" selected="" disabled=""></option>
   <option selected="" value="9.99">250</option>
   <option value="18">500</option>
   <option value="29">1000</option>
   <option value="54">2000</option>
   <option value="69">5000</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use [this codepen custom drop down .](https://codepen.io/wildc56/pen/EXXmOO)

```js
$(function() {
  var dd1 = new dropDown($('#myDropdown'));
  
  $(document).click(function() {
    $('.wrapper-dropdown').removeClass('active');
  });
});

function dropDown(el) {
  this.dd = el;
  this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
  this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
  this.val = '';
  this.index = -1;
  this.initEvents();
}
dropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents: function() {
    var obj = this;
    
    obj.dd.on('click', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      return false;
    });
    
    obj.opts.on('click', function() {
      var opt = $(this);
      obj.val = opt.text();
      obj.index = opt.index();
      obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

*,
*:focus,
*:visited {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  background: linear-gradient(50deg, #F9BF3B 0%,#F9BF3B 30%,#00B16A 30%,#00B16A 50%, #D64541 50%, #D64541 70%, #446CB3 70%, #446CB3 100%);
  
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  
  display: inline-block; 
  min-width: 290px;
  padding: 0 35px 0 15px;
  
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0 ,0 , 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #444;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.wrapper-dropdown::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 16px;
  
  margin-top: -2px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  
  border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #a0a0a0 transparent;
}

.wrapper-dropdown.active::before {
  border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  list-style: none;
  
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
  
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  -moz-transform-origin: top;
  -ms-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li {
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  overflow: hidden;
  
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li:hover {
  background: rgba(197, 239, 247, .55);
}

.wrapper-dropdown.active .dropdown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}



.new-class{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdown</h2>
  
  <div class="wrapper-dropdown" id="myDropdown">
    <span class='new-class'><span>weight </span><span></span>price </span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li  class='new-class'><span>50 k</span> <span>100$</span></li>
      <li  class='new-class'><span>100 k</span> <span>120$</span></li>
      <li  class='new-class'><span>100 k</span> <span>50$</span></li>
      <li  class='new-class'><span>70 k</span> <span>80$</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```